1:n - use of a Plugin or internal tools?
I want to use two tables in QGIS with which I want to achieve the following.
TabA should contain project names and TabB should contain log entries, i.e. a 1:n relationship. When entering a new log entry, I want to be able to select the project and then make the entry. Later, I want a window/GUI in which I can select the project in a combo box/drop-down box/combo box/list box/list view and then the log entries should appear in a list, sorted by the date of the log entry.
Can I achieve this using the built-in tools or do I need a plugin?

It can be done with built-in tool by setting up a relation between the two table and using a form with the relation editor widget. See QGIS manual : 16.4. Connecting and Editing Data Across Layers
There are also plugin like the Linking Relation Editor plugin for QGIS from OPENGIS that provide an alternative way
